SMAPI getExtendedMetadata called twice, getMediaURI never called, playback doesn't work
In the process of creating a SMAPI in Node with the soap package. So far I've got getMetadata working and can dive into albums and sub-albums.
My problem is that when I click a track, it will show as playing but never play and my API getMediaURI is never called. However what is called is getExtendedMetadata, twice.
Here's a sample integration between my implementation and Sonos:
<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+02:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>root</id>
            <index>0</index>
            <count>100</count>
        </ns:getMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <index>0</index>
            <count>100</count>
            <total>2</total>
            <getMetadataResult>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>wheel:soundwheel</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>SoundWheel</title>
                    <summary>SoundWheel summary</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>wheel:kidswheel</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>SoundWheel Kids</title>
                    <summary>SoundWheel Kids summary</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>wheel:workwheel</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>SoundWheel Work</title>
                    <summary>SoundWheel Work summary</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>wheel:youngwheel</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>SoundWheel Young</title>
                    <summary>SoundWheel Young summary</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
            </getMetadataResult>
        </getMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+02:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>wheel:soundwheel</id>
            <index>0</index>
            <count>100</count>
        </ns:getMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <index>0</index>
            <count>9</count>
            <total>9</total>
            <getMetadataResult>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Receive</title>
                    <summary>Receive in good faith. You are supported and held.</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:173b2bcf-080f-4820-9402-44e3e71631fc</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Ground</title>
                    <summary>Peace and grounding. Out of your mind and into your body.</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:f84b0106-d24b-44ea-a261-278d4be692ca</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Charge</title>
                    <summary>New energy into all of your cells and time to recharge your batteries.</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:c15ac5b5-0fe4-43c4-b7de-0e1ed5d82ef7</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Reconnect</title>
                    <summary>You&apos;re connected to it all through the connection to yourself. </summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:a8928b47-7fdb-4c80-8b1e-8af9863bd524</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Move</title>
                    <summary>Mental flexibility. Get over, under, through and onwards. </summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:9f02082e-a732-4b9d-94ec-c4a7f2ab2807</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Release</title>
                    <summary>Let go of the excess baggage. </summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:55b043a3-4449-4fa9-8c8b-f2fb5f6c7aef</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Create</title>
                    <summary>Manifest your dreams from a point of bliss.</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:31a62c8f-2030-457f-bae5-0a6603a178aa</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Rest</title>
                    <summary>Take a break and let it all stop for a moment.</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:ad52708a-a943-461b-a6ac-25feb80a8f6d</id>
                    <itemType>container</itemType>
                    <displayType>genreMood</displayType>
                    <title>Rise</title>
                    <summary>Face the depths within you. Ascend to new heights.</summary>
                    <canPlay>false</canPlay>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
            </getMetadataResult>
        </getMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+02:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getExtendedMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>wheel:soundwheel</id>
        </ns:getExtendedMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getExtendedMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getExtendedMetadataResult>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>wheel:soundwheel</id>
                    <itemType>album</itemType>
                    <title>SoundWheel</title>
                    <artist>SoundWheel</artist>
                    <artistId>soundwheel</artistId>
                    <canScroll>false</canScroll>
                    <canPlay>true</canPlay>
                    <canEnumerate>true</canEnumerate>
                    <canAddToFavorites>true</canAddToFavorites>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
            </getExtendedMetadataResult>
        </getExtendedMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+02:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</id>
            <index>0</index>
            <count>100</count>
        </ns:getMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <index>0</index>
            <count>4</count>
            <total>4</total>
            <getMetadataResult>
                <mediaMetadata>
                    <id>code:1137d375-a5f3-4edf-b748-ee1e29e874b9</id>
                    <mimeType>audio/mpeg</mimeType>
                    <itemType>track</itemType>
                    <title>Ocean</title>
                    <trackMetadata>
                        <albumId>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</albumId>
                        <duration>516</duration>
                        <album>Receive</album>
                        <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                    </trackMetadata>
                </mediaMetadata>
                <mediaMetadata>
                    <id>code:b6b80cf3-6b6f-4907-b4dc-43b1a886153a</id>
                    <mimeType>audio/mpeg</mimeType>
                    <itemType>track</itemType>
                    <title>We’ve got you</title>
                    <trackMetadata>
                        <albumId>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</albumId>
                        <duration>466</duration>
                        <album>Receive</album>
                        <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                    </trackMetadata>
                </mediaMetadata>
                <mediaMetadata>
                    <id>code:75ab85f3-47dc-4e32-9bf2-28a1f0a675d3</id>
                    <mimeType>audio/mpeg</mimeType>
                    <itemType>track</itemType>
                    <title>Starlight</title>
                    <trackMetadata>
                        <albumId>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</albumId>
                        <duration>589</duration>
                        <album>Receive</album>
                        <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                    </trackMetadata>
                </mediaMetadata>
                <mediaMetadata>
                    <id>code:fb383f43-764b-42e3-aa28-39cd870314e7</id>
                    <mimeType>audio/mpeg</mimeType>
                    <itemType>track</itemType>
                    <title>Heart massage</title>
                    <trackMetadata>
                        <albumId>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</albumId>
                        <duration>552</duration>
                        <album>Receive</album>
                        <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                    </trackMetadata>
                </mediaMetadata>
            </getMetadataResult>
        </getMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+02:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getExtendedMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</id>
        </ns:getExtendedMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getExtendedMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getExtendedMetadataResult>
                <mediaCollection>
                    <id>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</id>
                    <itemType>album</itemType>
                    <title>Receive</title>
                    <artist>SoundWheel</artist>
                    <artistId>soundwheel</artistId>
                    <canScroll>false</canScroll>
                    <canPlay>true</canPlay>
                    <canEnumerate>true</canEnumerate>
                    <canAddToFavorites>true</canAddToFavorites>
                    <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                </mediaCollection>
            </getExtendedMetadataResult>
        </getExtendedMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+02:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getExtendedMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>code:1137d375-a5f3-4edf-b748-ee1e29e874b9</id>
        </ns:getExtendedMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getExtendedMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getExtendedMetadataResult>
                <mediaMetadata>
                    <id>code:1137d375-a5f3-4edf-b748-ee1e29e874b9</id>
                    <itemType>track</itemType>
                    <title>Ocean</title>
                    <mimeType>audio/mp3</mimeType>
                    <trackMetadata>
                        <artistId>soundwheel</artistId>
                        <artist>SoundWheel</artist>
                        <albumId>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</albumId>
                        <album>Receive</album>
                        <duration>516</duration>
                        <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                        <canSkip>true</canSkip>
                        <canAddToFavorites>true</canAddToFavorites>
                    </trackMetadata>
                </mediaMetadata>
            </getExtendedMetadataResult>
        </getExtendedMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server received -->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>true</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getExtendedMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>code:1137d375-a5f3-4edf-b748-ee1e29e874b9</id>
        </ns:getExtendedMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!-- Server responded -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getExtendedMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getExtendedMetadataResult>
                <mediaMetadata>
                    <id>code:1137d375-a5f3-4edf-b748-ee1e29e874b9</id>
                    <itemType>track</itemType>
                    <title>Ocean</title>
                    <mimeType>audio/mp3</mimeType>
                    <trackMetadata>
                        <artistId>soundwheel</artistId>
                        <artist>SoundWheel</artist>
                        <albumId>theme:2b1bbc7b-288f-4a9d-8d5c-357631daaf11</albumId>
                        <album>Receive</album>
                        <duration>516</duration>
                        <albumArtURI>https://app.soundwheel.com/app.png</albumArtURI>
                        <canSkip>true</canSkip>
                        <canAddToFavorites>true</canAddToFavorites>
                    </trackMetadata>
                </mediaMetadata>
            </getExtendedMetadataResult>
        </getExtendedMetadataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

My interaction from this back and forth is this:
https://www.hiveworkshop.com/data/video/448/448239-237aeb2d4efe893a0e304bc437c038db.mp4
Aside from getMediaURI never being called, a curious thing is that sends this twice:

        <ns:getExtendedMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>code:1137d375-a5f3-4edf-b748-ee1e29e874b9</id>
        </ns:getExtendedMetadata>

Almost as if my response is not up to spec. But I have checked it so many times and it looks right to me.
Please tell me why Sonos never asks getMediaURI on the track called Ocean :)

I changed audio/mpeg to audio/mp3 and now it doesn't send the same request twice any more, but still no luck with getMediaURI.

I also just tried making sure the artistId and artist were the same. It did not make a difference.

The SMAPI security docs say that TLS 1.2 is a requirement and as I was reverse proxying my API through my Synology NAS, I wasn't aware it only supported 1.3. After allowing 1.2, the getMediaURI call started coming through.
https://docs.sonos.com/docs/security#tag/playback/operation/Playback-LoadContent-GroupId
